# Difference between MYSQLI/PDO for bind query

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

From the point of view of performance / safety, it is better to use PDO or mysqli for queries with bind?

Comment: what is your result? do you tested them and get any result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference as long as you are using both libraries properly.
There was one quite theoretical vulnerability in the older versions of PDO, fixed two years ago.